# how can i save XmL data from a URL into my database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I know how to load XML data into a string but I'm unable to store its content(content in the nodes of XML file) into my database. I have already tried many solutions but none of them are working in my case. XML link is:-

http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeedstopstories.cms

I just want to save the data that exist in the nodes of the XML file and the XML file is from a URL.

using (var client = new WebClient())
                 {
                string xmlData = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeedstopstories.cms");
                  XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                XmlNodeList nodeList = xml.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item");

```
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                var title = node["title"].InnerText;
                var description = node["description"].InnerText;
                var link = node["link"].InnerText;
                var guid = node["guid"].InnerText;
                var pubdate = node["pubDate"].InnerText;
                SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=vishal-pc\mssqlserver2012;Initial Catalog=aditya;User ID=sa;password=1234");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into XMLdata (title,description,link,guid,pubdate) VALUES (@xmlData,@xmlData1,@xmlData2,@xmlData3,@xmlData4)", cnn);
                cnn.Open();

                //string sqlForInsert = "INSERT INTO XMLdata (title,description,link,guid,pubdate) VALUES (@xmlData,@xmlData1,@xmlData2,@xmlData3,@xmlData4);";
                int rowsAffected = 0;
                //try
                //{
                //    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=vishal-pc\mssqlserver2012;Initial Catalog=aditya;User ID=sa;password=1234"))
                //    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlForInsert, con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlData", title));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlData1", description));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlData2", link));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlData3", guid));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlData4", pubdate));

                        rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cnn.Close();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enter code here

             using (var client = new WebClient())
             {
            string xmlData = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeedstopstories.cms");
              XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                 xml.LoadXml(xmlData);

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xml.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                var title = node["title"].InnerText;
                var description = node["description"].InnerText;
                var link = node["link"].InnerText;
                var guid = node["guid"].InnerText;
                var pubdate = node["pubDate"].InnerText;
                SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=vishal-pc\mssqlserver2012;Initial Catalog=aditya;User ID=sa;password=1234");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into XMLdata (title,description,link,guid,pubdate) VALUES (@xmlData,@xmlData1,@xmlData2,@xmlData3,@xmlData4)", cnn);


                //string sqlForInsert = "INSERT INTO XMLdata (title,description,link,guid,pubdate) VALUES (@xmlData,@xmlData1,@xmlData2,@xmlData3,@xmlData4);";
                int rowsAffected = 0;
                //try
                //{
                //    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=vishal-pc\mssqlserver2012;Initial Catalog=aditya;User ID=sa;password=1234"))
                //    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlForInsert, con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlData", title));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlData1", description));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlData2", link));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlData3", guid));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@xmlData4", pubdate));
                            cnn.Open();

                        rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        cnn.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: The only change is that there should exist a xml.LoadXml(string); and this will do the required job

Answer (score 0):

***Try this*** all you have to do:

1. Change the connection string
2. Change the insert query as your requirment
3. Add other parameters

   ```
   string xmlData = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeedstopstories.cms");
   string sqlForInsert = "INSERT INTO TableName (xmlDataField) VALUES (@xmlData);";
   int rowsAffected = 0;
   try
   {
       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("<ConnectionString>"))
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlForInsert, con))
       {
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("xmlData", xmlData));
           con.Open();
           rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
       //Exception Handling
   }
   if (rowsAffected > 0)
   {
       //Successful
   }
   else {
       //unsuccesfull
   }
   ```

Comment: still there exist a problem the data is not getting saved in database and there is no error even.can u help me out.thanks

Comment: what is the problem explain that anyone can help you out

Comment: please be make seor that your connection is opning and closing succesfully. otherwise check your connection string maybe that is the main problem

Comment: use connection string like this @"Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=databasename;User Id=sa;Password=password"

Comment: The connection string is in correct format even i have opened and closed the connection well but i m unable to judge what is the issue with it and why that data is not getting saved in database.please help.And tell me one  more thing that what to write in catch and IF and ELSE under it.

Comment: Have you visited the link from which i want to save data into my database.The link is:-http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeedstopstories.cms  from the above link i want to save data that exist in its nodes.Example:-The root node is <rss> then after its <channel> and under it there exist a node <item> with few nodes inside it i want to save the data that exist in the nodes of parent node<item>.

Comment: Add some codes what are you doing there also with the database structure so that i can help you

Comment: The database structure is the same as sent before. i made little changes in code and u can have a look at it.

Comment: check this i added to the answer please check it verify if it is work

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code.
Print exception message.
Check value of rowsAffected.
Check data type of xmlDataField column and the one in the SqlParameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
        XElement rssFeeds = null;
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                string rssString = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeedstopstories.cms");
                rssFeeds = XElement.Parse(rssString);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        if (rssFeeds != null)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=vishal-pc\mssqlserver2012;Initial Catalog=aditya;User ID=sa;password=1234"))
            {
                con.Open();
                var tran = con.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    rssFeeds.Descendants("item").ToList().ForEach(e =>
                    {
                        string insertSql = @"insert into XMLdata (title,description,link,guid,pubdate) VALUES (@title,@description,@link,@guid,pubdate)";
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSql, con, tran);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("title", e.Element("title").Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("description", e.Element("description").Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("link", e.Element("link").Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("guid", e.Element("guid").Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pubdate", e.Element("pubDate").Value));
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tran.Rollback();
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }

            }
        }
```